Nested lookup dictionaries in Typescript
I have a lot of data I need to sift through on the client side, and to do so I'm looking to use dictionaries for performance reasons.  I have the following data structure in JSON (somewhat truncated, as Values and Styles can have more data, but this is a shortened version so you can get the picture):
{
  "StyleNames": [
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Blah"
  ],
  "Styles": {
    "Foo": {
      "Dimensions": {
        "X": {
          "Values": {
            "0": 123,
            "10": 456,
            "50": 789
          }
        },
        "Y": {
          "Values": {
            "0": 123,
            "10": 456,
            "50": 789
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Bar": {
      "Dimensions": {
        "X": {
          "Values": {
            "0": 123,
            "10": 456,
            "50": 789
          }
        },
        "Y": {
          "Values": {
            "0": 123,
            "10": 456,
            "50": 789
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I'm having a difficult time getting the TypeScript classes right.  The goal is to be able to access a given value via something like this:
import data from './data.json';

let lookupData: ILookupData = data;
let value: number =  lookupData.Styles['Foo'].Dimensions['Y'].Values['10'];  // Gets a value of 50

The problem is at the let lookupData... step.  I'm getting the following (TL;DR for this block: nothing maps correctly):

"Type '{ StyleNames: string[]; Styles: { Foo: { Dimensions: { X: {
Values: { "0": number; "10": number; "50": number; }; }; Y: {
Values: { "0": number; "10": number; "50": number; }; }; }; };
Bar: { Dimensions: { X: { Values: { "0": number; "10": number;
"50": number; }; }; Y: { ...; }; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to
type 'ILookupData'.
Types of property 'Styles' are incompatible.
Type '{ Foo: { Dimensions: { X: { Values: { "0": number; "10":
number; "50": number; }; }; Y: { Values: { "0": number; "10":
number; "50": number; }; }; }; }; Bar: { Dimensions: { X: { Values:
{ "0": number; "10": number; "50": number; }; }; Y: { Values: {
"0": number; "10": number; "50": number; }; }; }; }; }' is not
assignable to type 'IRootStyle'.
Property '"Foo"' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ Dimensions: { X: { Values: { "0": number; "10": number;
"50": number; }; }; Y: { Values: { "0": number; "10": number;
"50": number; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IStyle'.
Types of property 'Dimensions' are incompatible.
Type '{ X: { Values: { "0": number; "10": number; "50": number;
}; }; Y: { Values: { "0": number; "10": number; "50": number; };
}; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, IDimension>'.
Property '"X"' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ Values: { "0": number; "10": number; "50": number; }; }'
is not assignable to type 'IDimension'.
Types of property 'Values' are incompatible.
Type '{ "0": number; "10": number; "50": number; }' is not
assignable to type 'Record<string, IValue>'.
Property '"0"' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'number'
is not assignable to type 'IValue'.

I've spent about two days trying everything I can find with regards to Record<T,U> associative arrays/dictionaries, and I'm unable (and possibly inexperienced enough with TypeScript) to figure out how to make an interface model that works here.  My current model is this:
export interface IValue {
    [key: string] : number;
}

export interface IDimension {
    Values: Record<string, IValue>
}

export interface IStyle {
    Dimensions: Record<string, IDimension>
}

export interface IRootStyle {
    [Name: string]: IStyle;
}

export interface ILookupData {
    Styles: IRootStyle;
    StyleNames: string[];
}

What am I missing here?

"I have a lot of data I need to sift through on the client side" this isn't wrong per se, there are plenty of cases where that's true, but 7/10 when someone says that to me IRL they're wrong FWIW. Also be aware since this is primarily a question about typing: you cannot strongly type at compile time data that you get from an API call at runtime. Make sure you're using appropriate runtime checks.

@JaredSmith Agreed, and I have a bunch of unit tests to ensure I have checks where possible.  That said, this is primarily a test/POC, so a lot of those checks will be built in later.

You were almost there. Record is used in a different context, for example Record<'Foo'|'Bar',IDimension>, then TS knows that the 2 possible keys are 'Foo' or 'Bar', and can type check that.
The solution is to drop Record and use index signatures. The following worked with your example:
export interface IValue {
  [key: string]: number;
}

export interface IDimension {
  Values: IValue;
}

export interface IStyle {
  Dimensions: { [key: string]: IDimension };
}

export interface IRootStyle {
  [Name: string]: IStyle;
}

export interface ILookupData {
  Styles: IRootStyle;
  StyleNames: string[];
}

Edit
On the back of what Jared mentioned (this was something bugging me when I wrote my answer). The mapping of the index signatures should be to an attribute that could be undefined, for example
export interface IRootStyle {
  [Name: string]: IStyle?;  // the key might not exist.
}


This worked perfectly.  Thank you!  And yeah, there's error checking that needs to go in like your edit said, but this is mostly a prototype at the moment.
